# Substitute for Tomato Paste in Lentil Soup

Tags: soup, lentils

​
I've been making a tried-and-true lentil soup recipe for many years and I now for dietary reasons have to eliminate one ingredient, tomato paste (or any tomato at all). I've tried a few substitutions but have yet to get the depth of flavor I get from the tomato paste.

Here's how I make it.
10 cups water
About 8 tsp. chicken base
1.5 cups lentils
Aromatics: onion, garlic
Spices/herbs: dried thyme, dried basic, bay leaf, ground pepper, salt
Vegetables: carrots, celery, green cabbage,
About 1/4 c tomato paste was added at the end.
Parsley or other greens are usually thrown in at the end.

I've tried two substitutions, neither being adequate:

- soy sauce: added 1/4 cup
- mushrooms (1.5 lbs sliced crimini cooked down with resulting broth part of the 10 cups liquid)

What other substitutions for tomato paste would give good depth of flavor to this soup?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to replace the umami flavor of the tomatoes - which is a good idea - but tomato paste is also very sweet and sometimes a little sour.  Try adding something sweet and something sour.

Comment: That's an interesting recipe; in most lentil soups, the tomato paste is added near the beginning of cooking, rather than at the end.

Comment: I always thought adding tomato paste early on would prohibit softening of the lentils. I must've read that somewhere over the years! When I say that I add it at the end, I do let the soup cook some more once added; I just wait to make sure the lentils are sufficiently tender.

Comment: Oh, no, not at all.  And if you add it at the beginning, with the onions, it cooks a bit more and develops stronger umami flavors.  This is true of pepper paste as well.

Comment: @Arlo Acidity in general hinders the softening of legumes (lentils, peas, beans...), but depending on the legume and the quantity of tomato paste added, this effect is not significant. On a chili recipe, however, that would be a problem (hence chili recipes calling for pre-cooked beans)

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza. Thanks for validating what I must've read years ago! What you say about amount makes sense. I'm now experimenting with making a red pepper paste and think this will definitely do the trick to enhance my mediocre mushroom lentil soup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this isn't prevented by your health condition, I'd recommend [sweet red pepper paste](https://www.grandturkishbazaar.com/product/sweet-pepper-paste-tat-550g-20oz/).  This is what Turkish folks traditionally use in lentil soup instead of tomato paste, and in my opinion it's better.  If you have a good international market near you, you can buy it premade.  If you don't, you can [make it yourself](https://ozlemsturkishtable.com/2010/04/turkish-hot-pepper-paste-biber-salcasi/) and keep it around as a general substitute for tomato paste.

If you have a nightshade allergy and peppers also aren't available to you, I would suggest using [a little tamarind paste](https://www.thespruceeats.com/tamarind-paste-overview-3217073), maybe half as much, possibly with a little (like 1/2 tsp) added sugar.

Comment: I agree with the comment about tomato having both sweet and sour, which explains why my mushroom substitute isn't cutting it. I will definitely try the sweet red pepper paste as well as the tamarind. Both are great ideas. Thank you.